# Виснет приложение при проверке MD5

Tags: java, android, md5

Я использую проверку MD5 файлов. Но при проверке приложение почему-то зависает.
Как исправить?

```
public static boolean checkMD5(Context context, String md5, File updateFile) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(md5) || updateFile == null) {
        Utils.writeLog(context, 'e', "MD5 string empty or updateFile null");
        return false;
    }

    String calculatedDigest = calculateMD5(context, updateFile);
    if (calculatedDigest == null) {
        Utils.writeLog(context, 'e', "calculatedDigest null");
        return false;
    }

    Utils.writeLog(context, 'i', "Calculated digest: " + calculatedDigest);
    Utils.writeLog(context, 'i', "Provided digest: " + md5);

    return calculatedDigest.equalsIgnoreCase(md5);
}

public static String calculateMD5(Context context, File updateFile) {
    MessageDigest digest;
    try {
        digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Utils.writeLog(context, 'e', "Exception while getting digest: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    InputStream is;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(updateFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Utils.writeLog(context, 'e', "Exception while getting FileInputStream: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int read;
    try {
        while ((read = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            digest.update(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        byte[] md5sum = digest.digest();
        BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, md5sum);
        String output = bigInt.toString(16);
        // Fill to 32 chars
        output = String.format("%32s", output).replace(' ', '0');
        return output;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to process file for MD5", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Utils.writeLog(context, 'e', "Exception on closing MD5 input stream: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Наверное потому что вы выполняете проверки в главном потоке. Как исправить - перенести их в фоновый поток, для выполнения фоновых задач существует не мало инструментов - от низкоуровневого `Thread` из коробки, до библиотек "на все случаи жизни" вроде `Rx`

Comment: совсем забыл об этом... точно.

Comment: Вот как сделал:

`if (response.body() != null) {
      if(!gamesList.getCache().isEmpty()) {
       new Thread(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < response.body().size(); i++) {
         File file = new File(Config.getGamePath(gameID) + response.body().get(i).path);
         if (!file.exists() || !Utils.checkMD5(context, response.body().get(i).size, file)) {
          new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {
// code
          });
         }
        }
       }).start();
      }`